# How do you find the amount of times a single character appears in a string and then store it into another string?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

here is the code I have right now:

```
String dog = "my!cat!is!brown!so!what!";
String temp = "";
for(int i = 0; i <= dog.length(); i++) {
    if(dog.charAt(i) == '!') {
        temp+= "a";
    }
}
```

I am trying to get it to the point where I can print "6" As and I don't know if I am heading in the wrong direction. Not asking for code just tips thanks.

Comment: "and then store it into another string?" - not clear. Store what into another string, the number of occurrences ? why not hold an `int` counter and display it ?

Comment: Ok, so... what is the problem? I can guess at a couple issues, but you haven't actually asked a concrete question yet.

Comment: How would I store the number of occurrences into an int? Would the if statement I have work?

Comment: System.out.println("count = " + dog.replace("!", "").length() - dog.length()); to offload the work, but otherwise yes, your if statement is ok, you just need to make temp an int instead of a string, and add 1 to it.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to create a counter prior to your for loop.  Then on every occurence of the char you are looking for, increment the counter.

```
int j = 0; //Don't use i since it is your loop counter

//Each occurence:
j++;
```

Then convert that int counter to your string object when the loop is complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(dog, dog[i]);
if(temp.indexOf(dog[i])==-1)
{
    temp+=dog[i]+": "+count+",";
}
```